Custom CSS for Azure Entra External ID: Styling Issues
I'm working on customizing the sign-in experience using Azure Entra External ID to match my website's dark mode theme. I'm having trouble applying certain CSS customizations, and would appreciate any advice on the following issues:

Input Placeholder Styling:

I want to change the color of input placeholders to gray in the sign-in form. However, my custom CSS doesn't seem to apply. Here’s what I’ve tried:
.ext-input.ext-text-box::placeholder { color: #6C7A8A; }


Expected behavior: Placeholder color changes to #6C7A8A.

Actual behavior: Placeholder remains the default color.





Identity Banner Styling:

I’d like to change the background color of the identity banner at the top of the sign-in form. I've tried this CSS:
.identityBanner { background-color: #2C3742; }


However, this doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to target this element?



Class Name Inconsistencies on Reset Password Page:

On the reset password page, the boilerplate-text class is used, while on other pages, the class ext-boilerplate-text is used. Since Azure's system only allows styling classes with the ext- prefix, I can't consistently style the reset password page.

Is this behavior by design? Is there any workaround for this limitation?




Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
According to Microsoft’s documentation, we are only allowed to style elements with class names starting with ext-, so we cannot currently update the styles on the reset password page? Not sure if we do have other way to do it.
Here’s my current custom CSS:
.ext-sign-in-box {
    padding: 40px 30px;
    background-color: #2C3742;
    color: white;
}

.ext-title {
    color: #fff;
}

.ext-button.ext-primary {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #000;
}

.ext-boilerplate-text {
    background-color: #2C3742;
    color: white;
}

.ext-input.ext-text-box::placeholder {
    color: #6C7A8A;
}

.ext-has-error {
    border-color: #ff7a00 !important;
}

.identityBanner {
    background-color: #2C3742;
}

According to Microsoft’s documentation, we can only target elements with classes starting with ext-. Does anyone know of a workaround for styling elements without this prefix on the reset password page?

The CSS you provided for changing the placeholder color should generally work. However, ensure that your CSS is not being overridden by other styles. You might try adding !important to your rule to enforce it, like this:
.ext-input.ext-text-box::placeholder { color: #6C7A8A !important; }

Hi Rukmini, thanks for the suggestion! I tried adding !important to the placeholder color rule, but it still didn’t work. It seems the CSS I added isn’t being detected at the element level.
